# TravisCI and SauceLabs - file does not exist on the file system

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, travis-ci, saucelabs

I have a project that has Protractor tests which are executed by TravisCI via SauceLabs.

One of the tests involve "uploading" a file:

```
it('should not allow "image/jpeg" file', function () {
  pathToFile = path.resolve(__dirname, 'file.jpg');
  elem.sendKeys(pathToFile);
  expect(elem.getAttribute('class')).toMatch('ng-invalid');
});
```

This works fine locally, however Travis produces an error:

**. . . ./file.jpg' does not exist on the file system**

I think this is because `file.png` doesn't exist on SauceLabs.

My question is, how can I get this to work?

The directive in question is this one: https://github.com/GrumpyWizards/ngValidation/blob/master/wizValidation/src/file/file.dir.js

Comment: Can you give a bit more information on the element/directive you're testing?

Comment: Looks like there is a function `setFileDetector`, explained at http://saucelabs.com/resources/selenium-file-upload,  that can theoretically get this working. However, from https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/612 and https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6048#c3 , it looks like at the moment, there isn't a Node binding, and so won't be accessible from Protractor until it's added (or you add it: but I'm not sure if you can use a custom build of Selenium with Sauce?)

Comment: Same issue with my plugin here: http://ng-form-data.tomchentw.com/

Comment: I got the same conclusion for Michal's comment here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a UI test, there is no need to resolve a path name at all...

```
it('should not allow "image/jpeg" file', function () {
  pathToFile = "path/is/not/important/file.jpg";
  elem.sendKeys(pathToFile);
  expect(elem.getAttribute('class')).toMatch('ng-invalid');
});
```

Michael

Comment: The element uses the HTML5 File API to read the details of the file though